# Auto Number Format

Tags: ms-access, format, autonumber

I currently have an auto number field populated in the format "\E00000".

After some thought I would like to change the auto number to the date that it is made (today's date) and then an incremented value after that, because there may be multiple records being made a day.

Example - E11072018-01 or - E11/07/2018-01

If this is possible to be created as an auto number please let me know.

Comment: That is not possible. You must run your own function to maintain such a number.

Comment: Okay and how would i run my own function to do this?

Comment: I often wonder what purpose this sort of numbering will serve, a date created field will give you this and be eminently more useful. Have a read here about autonumbers http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/Autonumbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use this fancy expression to obtain the next "number":

```
= Format(Date(), "\Nddmmyyyy\-") & Format(Nx(DMax("Val(Right([NumberField], 2))", "[SomeTable]", "[NumberField] Like Format(Date(), '\Nddmmyyyy\-??'"), 0), "00")
```

Of course, replace field and table names with those of yours.

To set value in *BeforeInsert* event:

```
Me!NumberField.Value = Format(Date(), "\Nddmmyyyy\-") & Format(Nx(DMax("Val(Right([NumberField], 2))", "[SomeTable]", "[NumberField] Like Format(Date(), '\Nddmmyyyy\-??'"), 0), "00")
```

Comment: ah i see, so it would be a way of making my own auto number! thanks!

Comment: Where would i insert this code then? in the table (format options for that field)? in the form? in an event?

Comment: It could be in the _BeforeInsert_ event of the form.

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to work i'm afraid, there seems to be a syntax error, here is the code i have place "=Format(Date(), "\Nddmmyyyy\-") & Format(Nx(DMax("Val(Right([Enquiry ID], 2))", "[Job Listings]", "[Enquiry ID] Like Format(Date(), '\Nddmmyyyy\-??'"), 0), "00")"

Comment: The "Nx" comes up with a "sub or function not defined"

Comment: Nz it is. Sorry,

Comment: A run time error now shows '3075' 'Missing),], or item in query expression '[enquiry_ID] Like Format(Date(),'\Nddmmyyyy\-??".